# Faster calculation histogram of a set of images

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, histogram

I have about 3 million images and need to calculate a histogram for each one. Right now I am using python but it is taking of lot of time. Is there any way to process the images in batches? I have NVIDIA 1080 Ti GPU cards, so maybe if there is a way to process on the GPU?

I can't find any code or library to process the images in parallel. Any kind of help to boost up the speed is appreciated

Comment: You don't say what you have been trying so far, so it's hard to tell what might be better. Depending on your application, perhaps you can use `np.bincount` instead of `np.histogram`, which is much faster as it doesn't perform the binning for arbitrary floating point numbers and arbitrary ranges. Also, did you verify that the actual histogram calculation is your bottleneck, and not, for example, I/O?

Comment: So far I was using a for loop, as mentioned in my question. I call `numpy.histogram` for each image. Regarding 2nd part of your query, yes, histogram calculation is the bottleneck. I am doing some other processing along with histogram calculation. If I comment out the histogram portion, the code runs well.

Comment: `np.histogram` is unnecessarily slow for this specific task. On my laptop `np.bincount` is about 5x faster. OpenCV also has a histogram function that might be even faster (I haven't tried it). [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html) are examples for all three methods.

Answer (score 0):

Python is among the slowest production-ready languages you can use.

As you haven't posted any code, I can only provide general suggestions. They are listed in order of practicality below:

- Use a compiled version of python, such as pypy or cpython
- Use existing software with your desired functionality. There's nothing wrong with finding free software online.
- Use a more efficient (or perhaps even lossy) algorithm to skip computation
- Use a faster language such as Rust, C++, C#, or Java

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried multiprocessing package for such heavy calculation tasks? Since I assume you don't care about the order in which those images are processed.

A sample use will be:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool 

pool = Pool()
results = pool.map(create_histogram, images)
```

Comment: This approach looks promising. However, I am doing some more image processing other than histogram calculation. I want to run only the histogram part in the above mentioned fashion as that seems to be the bottleneck. As soon as the execution enters the `Pool`, it seems like it starts executing the whole code in various threads.